# Retrieve all storage with less than 10% free Disk Space

Tags: powershell

its been ages since I program or script in anything but SQL and due to constrains need to get a script that would show me all storage (mount point included) with less than 10%, so far I have come here but I am still stuck on how to do the iterator.

I am struggling with formating the email any help there?

```
    $TotalGB = @{Name="Capacity(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.Capacity/ 1073741824),2)}}
    $FreeGB = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824),2)}}
    $FreePerc = @{Name="Free(%)";expression={[math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0)}}

    $emailFrom="example@example.com"
    $emailTo="test@example.com"

    function get-mountpoints {
$volumes = Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter "DriveType='3'" -ComputerName someComputer| Where-Object {$_.DriverLetter -eq $null}
if(($volumes | Select VolumeName, Label, $TotalGB, $FreeGB, $FreePerc | ?{$_."Free(%)" -lt 20} | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0)
{
    $volumes | Select VolumeName, Label, $TotalGB, $FreeGB, $FreePerc | ?{$_."Free(%)" -lt 20} | Format-Table -AutoSize
    $Subject="Disk $volumes.Label on $hostname has less than $volumes.$FreeGB GB of free space left, which is $volumes.$FreePerc %" | ?{$_."Free(%)" -lt 20} 
    Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo  -Subject $Subject -Body $Subject -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer "smtp.mail.com" -Port 25  
}
}

get-mountpoints
```

This was the final solution I come up with.

```
$emailFrom = "mail@mail.com"
$emailTo = "tomail@mail.com"
function Get-Mountpoints {
    param(
        $ComputerName, 
        $FreePercentage,
        $Filter ="DriveType='3'"
    )

  $volumes = Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter $Filter -ComputerName $ComputerName |
    Where-Object {$_.DriverLetter -eq $null -and ([math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0)) -lt $FreePercentage} 

    if($volumes) {

        # You might want to use the header of the body below, whatever.
        $Subject = "Issue for space on server $ComputerName"

        # When referencing parameter values in a string, you need to tell powershell to evaluate your string in a special way
        # Wrapping things in a $() essentially is an order of operations for evaluation, the more nested, the earlier you will be evaluated
        # You can also use this $() when your variable name abuts a character, like in the % below 
        $Body = "Hostname: $ComputerName `r`n" + [System.Environment]::NewLine # a "shortcut" for system anonymous newlines
        $Body += 
            # If you comment out $Volumes and replace it with the next line, you will get two rows output into $Body
             $Volumes | 
            #  @( [pscustomobject]@{Label = "C"; FreeSpace = 10;}, [pscustomobject]@{Label = "C"; FreeSpace = 10;})  | 
            Foreach-Object {
                "Disk $($_.Label) has less than $([math]::round(($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824),2)) GB of free space left, which is $([math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0))% `r`r"
            }
        # In PowerShell, these messages will be supressed unless the console runs $VerbosePreference="Continue" indicating you would like to see more verbose output 
        # I added the -WhatIf so you wont send anything
        #$VerbosePreference="Continue"
        Write-Verbose "From: $emailFrom To: $emailTo"
        Write-Verbose $Subject
        Write-Verbose $Body
        Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer "smtp.mail.com" -Port 25
      }
    }

# Why not maintain a list of computers? 
$ComputerList = @(
    "localhost"
)
$ComputerList | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Mountpoints -ComputerName $_ -Filter "DriveType='3'" -FreePercentage 20
} # I Added some parameters so you can make it a little more flexible
```

Thanks all for your help

Comment: you should also move that Select in the foreach loop into the definition of volumes

Comment: @OwainEsau I am sorry what do you mean by the definition you mean on the WMI call?

Comment: Made a bit of progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took some major liberties with your question and tried to get at the intent, I added comments throughout, put some parameters in to make a little more flexible, demonstrated list, string evaluation, and a few other pieces.

```
$emailFrom = "example@example.com"
$emailTo = "test@example.com"

function Get-Mountpoints {
    param(
        $ComputerName, 
        $FreePercentage,
        $Filter ="DriveType='3'"
    )

  $Volumes = Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter $Filter -ComputerName $ComputerName |
    Where-Object {$_.DriverLetter -eq $null -and $_."Free(%)" -lt $FreePercentage} 

  if($Volumes){

    # You might want to use the header of the body below, whatever.
    $Subject = "To Be Determined"

    # When referencing parameter values in a string, you need to tell powershell to evaluate your string in a special way
    # Wrapping things in a $() essentially is an order of operations for evaluation, the more nested, the earlier you will be evaluated
    # You can also use this $() when your variable name abuts a character, like in the % below 
    $Body = "Hostname: $ComputerName" + [System.Environment]::NewLine # a "shortcut" for system anonymous newlines
    $Body += 
        # If you comment out $Volumes and replace it with the next line, you will get two rows output into $Body
        $Volumes | 
        #  @( [pscustomobject]@{Label = "C"; FreeSpace = 10;}, [pscustomobject]@{Label = "C"; FreeSpace = 10;)  | 
        Foreach-Object {
            "Disk $($_.Label) has less than $([math]::round(($_.FreeSpace + .1 / 1073741824),2)) GB of free space left, which is $([math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace + .1 / 1073741824)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0))%" + [System.Environment]::NewLine
        } # $_ indicates the current iterated on item 

    # In PowerShell, these messages will be supressed unless the console runs $VerbosePreference="Continue" indicating you would like to see more verbose output 
    # I added the -WhatIf so you wont send anything
    Write-Verbose "From: $emailFrom To: $emailTo"
    Write-Verbose $Subject
    Write-Verbose $Body

    #Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer "smtp.mail.com" -Port 25
  }
}


# Why not maintain a list of computers? 
$ComputerList = @(
    "localhost"
)
$ComputerList | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Mountpoints -ComputerName $_ -Filter "DriveType='5'" -FreePercentage 99
} # I Added some parameters so you can make it a little more flexible
```

Comment: Variables are not been past to the email, not even hostname weirdly enough.

Comment: Heh, -WhatIf is not supported for Send-MaiMessage (I added that after our conversation without testing it) I am surprised this ran at all for you... one second

Comment: I actually comment that part :P still facing issues

Comment: What issues are you seeing if you comment that out? Did you want to see the subject and body? If so you will need to run $VerbosePreference="Continue" in your console before you run this

Comment: Also note I did change the filter and free percentages for testing on my machine.